# disable xmlstarlet rewriting quotes

Tags: quoting, xmlstarlet

How can I stop xmlstarlet from rewriting all the quotes in a file.

For example,

```
<value restricted='false'>Sunday</value>
```

becomes

```
<value restricted="false">Sunday</value>
```

Which creates a lot of unnecessary diff changes in git.

Comment: Edit your Q to show the minimal example of `xmlstarlet` usage that causes this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe only store the [canonical representation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s06.html) in git?